# Finding local maxima, minima, saddle points of a 2 variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the local maxima, minima, saddle points of a $2$ variable function: $$f(x,y)=(1+e^y)\cos(x)-ye^y$$ I have trouble determining the values of the critical points for this function. I take the $f_x$ derivative: $$ -(1+e^y)\sin(x)=0$$ I take the $f_y$ derivative  $$e^y\cos(x)-e^y-ye^y=0$$ Now I know that I have to find such values of $x$ and $y$ such that for these values both equations will equal to $0$. However, I am stuck and cannot do that. If you could guide me through how to determine the values, I can finish the problem after calculating second partials, etc. Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the first equation you get $x = k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and so you get $\cos x = (-1)^k$. When you plug it in the second equation you get $e^y((-1)^k-1-y)=0$. Now you just have to solve it for even $k$ and odd $k$. For even $k$ you get $y=0$ and for odd $k$ you get $y=-2$. Therefore the critical points are of the form $(2k \pi, 0), k \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $((2k+1)\pi, -2), k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you, so i get for even k y=0 and for odd y=-2; Now I just take the second derivative and check those 2 spots with x=0 for evens and x=pi for odds, and the maxima, minima will repeat for all other values of x?

Comment: The function is periodic with respect to $x$, so yes, the conclusions you get for those two points will characterize all others.